# mkdirs() method not works

Tags: android, mkdirs

I need to make a directory if not exist. I've wrote codes below

```
    File backupDir = new File("//test");

    // if (!backupDir.exists())
    backupDir.mkdirs();
```

I've previously used it without any problem, But now not works and I have no errors! What is the problem? Have you any idea to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have you any idea to solve this?

Use a valid path that you can write to. Not only is `//test` a strange way to encode a path, you cannot write to it on any Android device from Java code this way. Use appropriate methods, like `getFilesDir()` or `getExternalFilesDir()`, to find places that you can write to.

Comment: Thanks, Do you know how can I get the root directory of internal storage?

Comment: @MousaJafari: If you really mean [internal storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), you cannot write to the root of internal storage.

Comment: Yes I know, I'm sorry my point was not root directory. I want to make a folder near the folders such as Data, System (Root directory)

Comment: @MousaJafari: You do not have write access there. Apps running on rooted devices should have some ability to write there, but I do not know the details.